# What is the minimal polynomial of $\alpha = i \sqrt{ 1 + i \sqrt{3}}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

What is the minimal polynomial of $\alpha = i \sqrt{ 1 + i \sqrt{3}}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$?

---

I calculated $\alpha, \alpha^2, ....$ until I saw a linear combination (with coefficients in $\mathbb{Q}$) such that it is equal to 0. I ended up finding the following polynomial:

$f(X) = X^4 + 2X^2 + 4$ which gives:

$f(\alpha) = -2 + 2 i \sqrt{3} + 2(-1 -i \sqrt{3}) + 4 = -4 + 4 - 0$.

I wanted to know if there was a shorter way of finding the minimal polynomial for $\alpha$ because calculating all the powers and then looking for a linear combination requires quite a lot of calculations.

Comment: Note that the comment of @DietrichBurde is **possibly** based on the **intuition** that $\frac{-(\alpha^2)}{2}$ is **some root** of $(z^3 + 1) = 0$ **other than** $z = -1$.  Consequently, $\frac{-(\alpha^2)}{2}$ must be a root of $$0 = \frac{z^3 + 1}{z +1} = (z^2 - z + 1).$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can just square the equation, rearrange and square again. This gives a polynomial of degree $4$, and we only have to show that it is irreducible.

So we obtain $\alpha^2=-(1+\sqrt{-3})$ and then $(\alpha^2+1)^2=-3$, i.e., $\alpha^4+2\alpha^2+4=0$. Hence the polynomial is $x^4+2x^2+4$.

The polynomial is irreducible over $\Bbb Q$ and $\Bbb Z$. One way to see this is to assume that
$x^4+2x^2+4=(x^2+ax^2+b)(x^2+cx^2+d)$ and compare coefficients. This has no integral solution.

Comment: Oh I see! Thank you so much :)